How do you test react-aria-components for the custom props you passed in?
The components render fine on a live local server and everythign works fine. But I can't figure out how to test the components for the react-aria-library. I know they are already tested by the creators, but I want to implement them into my unit/integrated/end-to-end tests.
Here is a basic example.
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { describe, it, expect } from "vitest";
import { Button } from "react-aria-components";

describe("Button Component", () => {
  it("renders a regular button", () => {
    render(<button />);
    const buttonElement = screen.getByRole("button");
    expect(buttonElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
  it("renders a react-aria-button", () => {
    render(<Button />);
  });
});

I set up the testing environment and import the stuff I need, including the Button component from the library.
I then run 2 tests, both of which render a simple button. The first test renders a regular/manually created button, and the second one uses the <Button> component from the library.
The results:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

❯ Button Component (2)
  ✓ renders a regular button (passed)
  × renders a react-aria-button (failed)

...
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

It's producing an error without even expecting anything. The problem is that the component uses a utility function with a useContext hook which triggers the error. Adobe docs say that each component uses a context hook, which means this error will occur with all components.
I'm a rookie. Would appreciate any help I could get.

The solution was a simple reboot of everything. I'm still not sure what the problem was, but it did the trick.
